# Can't see controllers in any scene of VRTK using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

Using :

- Unity v5.5
- VRTK v3.2.1
- SteamVR v1.2.3 (HTC Vive)

I can't see (nor use) my controllers in any VRTK's example scene. I also tried to add a `SteamVR_UpdatePoses` in `[CameraRig]->Camera (head)->Camera(eye)` as the [FAQ](https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK/blob/master/Assets/VRTK/Documentation/FAQ.md#im-using-unity-56-and-steamvr-but-i-cannot-see-my-controllers-in-any-of-the-example-scenes) suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam vr 1.2.3 no longer works with the adding component because it added more stuff that made the issue worse.

You need to edit the steam vr code to fix the issue

https://steamcommunity.com/app/358720/discussions/0/1634111706735965184

Comment: Wow thanks I've searched a lot for this. Deleting the lines 340 to 343 in the file `SteamVR/Scripts/SteamVR_Render.cs` in the `OnCameraPreCull` method did the trick.